# Problem 1.5.17 in Karatzas and Shreve

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I'm reading through Karatzas and Shreve Browninan motion and stochastic calculus and the problem $5.17$ asks:
[image]

The solution of this problem is based on localization and is included on the book:
[image]

I understand how they define the process $\langle X\rangle_t$ however I think that this definition works for almost every $\omega\in \Omega$ as we could have a set of probability zero such that $R_n$ doesn't converge. I also can't see why the process is adapted for the same reason.

Comment: At the start of that section 1.5 K&S mention that the filtration $({\cal F})_t$ shall satisfy the *usual conditions*. This is exactly to address those issues.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how having the usual conditions helps me here.

Comment: Please ask a more specific question. Hint: If $U_t=V_t$ are equal almost surely then, say, $U_t$ is ${\cal F}_t$ measurable where the filtration is the completion of $({\cal F}^V_t)\,.$